# Swagger is not showing @Api annotation for jersey when using Application subclass

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger

I am trying to document my jersey REST API using swagger, but I can not manage to get it to document any method or API. I can get the properties that I set in the MainAPI when I access host/api/swagger.json and that's about it. 
I have 1 main Application subclass called MainAPI which looks like this:

```
ApplicationPath("api")
public class MainAPI extends Application{

public MainAPI(){
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("api");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}


@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet();

    resources.add(FirstAPI.class);
    resources.add(SecondAPI.class);

    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

    return resources;
}
}
```

Then I have another class which defines some api functionality called FirstAPI. Code looks like this:

```
@Path("login")
@Api(value="user", description = "Login and check login status")
public class FirstAPI extends MainAPI {

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Test method",
              notes = "This is test method")
    @Path("test")
    public Response testMethod() {

        return Response.status(200).entity("Hello Martians!").build();
    }

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Check if any user is loggedin",
        notes = "If an user is loggedin the username will be returned",
        response = Response.class)
    // @Path("/login")
    public Response checkLogin(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject();
        if (true) {
            myJson.put("loggedin", "true");
            myJson.put("user", "John Doe");
            return Response.status(200).entity(myJson.toString()).build();
        } else {
            myJson.put("loggedin", "false");
            return Response.status(200).entity(myJson.toString()).build();
        }
    }
   }
```

I am running this on Tomcat 7 with jersey 1.13.

Comment: Have you configured swagger to look into the package containing the other class?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia Can I configure that from  MainAPI?

Comment: I haven't used it in a while, but somewhere in your json/xml configs you should ahve specified a package path to "look into" for annotated classes (which should include your MainAPI). If you add the package of the other class too then it should auto-pick it up.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia BINGO!  beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources"); I should've pointed that to my code. Now I get the information I annotated. Thanks. If you want to write a quick response mentioning this I can accept it, as you figured this thing out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your Swagger configuration (either json, xml or via code) there should be a resources package. You need to add your annotated classes' packages to that, so that swagger will auto-pick them up.
Something like

```
 beanConfig.setResourcePackage("my.package.is.the.best");
```